# More @ngrx/effects

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201562/redux-and-ngrx-effects) a while ago surrounding the `@ngrx/effects` library but the responses do not resolve my issue entirely.

I am now happy that I understand how actions and effects relate to each other, but I am still unsure as to what functions they perform. The [example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app) goes some way to helping me, but it seems that the effects are doing all the grunt work: the `loadCollection$` effect, for example, appears to be loading all of the resources; and a subsequent dispatch of an `AddBookSuccessAction` appears to add the book to the collection.

In this app, the `AddBookAction` appears to do nothing in the reducer, but the effect is loading the resource and dispatching a success action.

I guess really what I want to know is about separation of concerns: what should actions be doing, and what should effects be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you introduce `@ngrx/effects` into your application, you need to think a little bit differently. Take for example a login component and a user state

```
@Component({})
class LoginComponent {

  login(form: any) { // implementation }
}

@Component({})
class AppComponent {
  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.user = store.select('user');
  }
}
```

Without using effects, your `login` implementation might look something like

```
login(form: any) {
  this.authService.login(new Credentials(form))
    .map(res => res.json() as User)
    .subscribe(user => {
      this.store.dispatch({ type: UPDATE_USER, payload: user });
    });
}
```

When the `dispatch` is called, the action is used by the reducer to update the user state. So the action doesn't really *do* anything. The reducer can use the payload to update the state, based on the action. The subscribing (in this case) `AppComponent` will get the updated user.

When you introduce effects, the main difference is how the `login` is handle. Nothing changes about the `USER_UPDATED` action *or* the user reducer. What changes is that you introduce another action, that is dispatched by the `login` method. So now your new `login` is simply

```
login(form: any) {
  this.store.dispatch({ type: LOGIN, payload: form })
}
```

Now the purpose of the effect, is to handle what would normally have been handled in the `login`. It will listen for the `LOGIN` action, and then transform itself into the `USER_UPDATED` action.

```
@Injectable()
class LoginEffects {
  constructor(private actions: Actions, private authService: AuthService) {}

  @Effect
  login$ = this.actions
    .ofType(LOGIN)
    .map(action => new Credentials(action.payload))
    .switchMap(credentials => {
      return this.authService.login(credentials)
        .map(res => res.json() as User)
        .map({ type: USER_UPDATED, payload: user })
    });
}
```

You can see that from the `LOGIN` action, we get the credentials, and use `switchMap` to return different Observable, one that contains the new (UPDATED_USER) Action. So it's just a transformation. No one has to call the effect. This is automatically subscribed to.

The benefit of doing it this way, is that it makes your component simpler, and easier to test. Also puts all the side effects into one place, which makes it easier to reason about and test. All your components do is subscribe to state and dispatch actions. The effect will handle all the legwork and dispatch the appropriate resulting actions.

As far as the *"Action Classes"*, these are not mandatory. An `Action` is nothing more than an object with two properties `type` and `payload` that get passed to the reducer. The purpose of having action classes is to act as action *creators*. For example

```
class UserActions {
  static readonly USER_UPDATED = 'USER_UPDATE';

  userUpdated(user: User): Action {
    return {
      type: UserActions.USER_UPDATED,
      payload: user
    }
  }
}
```

Now instead of creating the actions yourself, you just call the appropriate method to get the action

```
constructor(private userActions: UserActions) {}

@Effect
login$ = this.actions
  .ofType(LOGIN)
  .map(form => new Credentials(form))
  .switchMap(credentials => {
    return this.authService.login(credentials)
      .map(res => res.json() as User)
      .map(this.userActions.updateUser(user))
  });
```

You can see the last `map` call where we create the `Action` just be calling the `userActions.updateUser`.

There are a few benefits to doing this. For one, you get strong typing. When you create the action yourself, there's a chance you might pass the wrong payload. But when you have a method for which you know what the argument type needs to be, you have less chance of a mistake.

Also when you use the action creators, you can accept different arguments. It doesn't have to be the payload. This way you can create the payload yourself (and may introduce some logic) in a reproducible and testable way.

**See Also:**

- [Using Effects in an Angular 2 NgRx Application](https://psamsotha.github.io/angular/2016/12/31/ngrx-effects-with-angular.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer. Makes a lot of sense. So am I right in thinking that the reducer for your login scenario would not perform any function given this action? And that the async login is handled by the effect?

Comment: In this case, yeah, all the reducer would do is return the action payload, in the case of the USER_UPDATED action. But this is not always the case, that the new state _is_ the payload.

Comment: As far as the login, yes it is handle by the effect, as you can see it calling the `authService.login`, which ends up just mapping to the new user, which is what is passed as the action payload to the reducer

Comment: That's really great, what a fabulous explanation. I feel prepared to develop my own effects-based apps now. It's a bit like the shift from regular Angular 2 to RxJS, bit of a mind melt. Thanks again.